# ImportError: cannot import name aliases

Tags: python, windows, installation

I just installed the Python 2.7.1 on Windows Vista using installer from [official site](http://www.python.org/download), and get such error when run python.exe

```
C:\Python27>python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site.py", line 553, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site.py", line 542, in main
    aliasmbcs()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site.py", line 467, in aliasmbcs
    import locale, codecs
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\locale.py", line 15, in <module>
    import encodings
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from encodings import aliases
ImportError: cannot import name aliases
```

With Python 3.1.3, also just installed

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python31\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name aliases

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

What is going on? Should I configure PYTHONPATH or some thing like this? If so, what values should it have?

Comment: Have you installed "for all users"? Do you have an HP machine with a default Python in PATH?

Comment: Yes, installed for all users. Running as administrator. There is no python in %PATH%. But I tried with it, and same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reference I could find points to a virus problem:

Starts here: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2009-January/066730.html
Goes through: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2009-January/066739.html
And ends: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2009-January/066750.html

If your `\Lib\encodings\aliases.py` is missing and you cannot create a file with that name there, start looking for the trojan.

Comment: Haha, hilarious, "I had a trojan on my system which hid all the files whose names started with 'ali'."